# What is the number of inter partitions of an arbitrary positive integer $n$ that consist of only primes?

Tags: number-theory

I would like to know that when given a positive integer, how to find the number of sets of only prime numbers that sum up to it.  For example, if $n=13$, one such set comes from $3 + 5 + 5 = 13$.

Is there a formula for this? I am trying for the number $13$, there is $9$ in total but I can only find $8$.

---

A professional mathematician would ask the problem this way:

What is the number of integer partitions of an arbitrary positive integer $n$ that consist of only primes?

Comment: Can you show those $8$ that you found?

Comment: It is 2*5+3, 2*4+5, 2*3+7, 2*2+3*3,2+11,2+3*2+5,3+5*5,3*2+7

Comment: @chem1kal Since it doesn't say there must be $2$ or more prime numbers being used, I believe that $13 = 13$ itself may be included in the count of $9$.

Comment: Are you asking how many partitions of $n$ exist, such that all terms (summands) are prime?

Comment: Goldbach's conjecture demonstrates how difficult questions about sums of primes are in general. Considering this, it is very hard to imagine that there is an easy formula , in particular if the given number is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [A000607](https://oeis.org/A000607) there dosen't seem to be an easy formula.

In this sequence it counts partitions, the number itself as a sum is a partition.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some context. In general, the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for the number $p_S(n)$ ways to partition an integer $n$ into a sum of elements of a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ of the natural numbers is

$$f_S(z) = \prod_{s \in S} \frac{1}{1 - z^s}.$$

If $S$ is finite these are [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) and closed forms for $p_S(n)$ can be given; for example, if $S = \{ 1, 5, 10, 25 \}$ we are counting the number of ways to make change for $n$ cents using pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters.

These are very complicated functions if $S$ is infinite. When $S = \mathbb{N}$ we get what is just called the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) $p_{\mathbb{N}}(n) = p(n)$, with generating function

$$f_{\mathbb{N}}(z) = \frac{1}{(1 - z)(1 - z^2)(1 - z^3) \dots}.$$

The infinite product appearing in the denominator is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function). $p(n)$ has no closed form but Hardy and Ramanujan famously showed that it is asymptotic to

$$p(n) \sim \frac{1}{4n \sqrt{3}} \exp \left( \pi \sqrt{ \frac{2n}{3} } \right)$$

and a complete asymptotic expansion is known and due to Rademacher. I say all this to emphasize that even when $S = \mathbb{N}$ this is a complex and deep problem.

Nevertheless some things can be said. In the context of Flajolet and Sedgewick's *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html)* problems of this type can be dealt with using *saddle-point asymptotics*, which are at least good enough to give asymptotics for the logarithm

$$\boxed{ \log p_{\mathbb{P}}(n) \sim 2\pi \sqrt{ \frac{n}{3 \log n} } }$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ is the primes; this is VIII.26. I don't know the details of the analysis unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a formula, but it is very simple coding:  In *Mathematica*:

```
n=13;
Select[IntegerPartitions[n], AllTrue[#, PrimeQ] &]
```

which gives the nine sequences:

(*
{{13}, {11, 2}, {7, 3, 3}, {7, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 3}, {5, 3, 3, 2},
{5, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}
*)

for $n=8$:

(* {{5, 3}, {3, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}} *)

The number of such sequences (comprising only primes) increases very rapidly with $n$:

[image]